# Unable to Automatically Update Leaflet.js Map when Table Data Changes in Filamentphp

Tags: javascript, laravel, leaflet, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament

I'm using Filament to build the user interface for my Laravel application, and I'm facing an issue with automatically updating a Leaflet.js map when the table data changes.

I'm using a Filament widget to display a map containing data from a school table. I'm using Leaflet.js to build the map, and I'm fetching school data from the currently active table.

Here's an example of the PHP code I'm using to fetch school data:

```
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Resources\SekolahResource\Widgets;

use App\Filament\Resources\SekolahResource\Pages\ListSekolahs;
use Filament\Widgets\Concerns\InteractsWithPageTable;
use Filament\Widgets\Widget;

class PetaSekolahOverview extends Widget
{
    use InteractsWithPageTable;

    protected int $zoomLevel = 15;

    public $sekolah = null;

    protected function getTablePage(): string
    {
        return ListSekolahs::class;
    }

    public function allSekolahMap()
    {
        $sekolah = $this->getPageTableRecords();

        // Process school data into GeoJSON format
        // ...
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->sekolah = $this->allSekolahMap();

        return view('filament.resources.sekolah-resource.widgets.peta-sekolah-overview')
            ->with($this->sekolah);
    }
}
```

I want to note that the map displays correctly when the widget is first accessed, according to the data available in the table. However, when I load another page in the table viewer, the map view doesn't change.

Here's a snippet of the Blade code I'm using to display the map:

```
<x-filament-widgets::widget>
    <x-filament::section>
        <div id="map" style="height: 400px; z-index:0;" x-data="{
            init() {
                const map = L.map('map').setView([-8.6042279, 115.1761774], {{ $this->zoomLevel }});
                L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    maxZoom: 19,
                    attribution: `<a href='http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap</a>`
                }).addTo(map);
        
                let geoSekolah = {{ $this->sekolah }};
                let layerSekolah = L.geoJSON(geoSekolah).addTo(map);
                map.fitBounds(layerSekolah.getBounds());
            }
        }" wire:ignore>

        </div>
    </x-filament::section>
</x-filament-widgets::widget>
```

Can anyone provide advice or a solution as to why the map isn't automatically updated with new data every time the table changes? I would greatly appreciate any help and insights from the community. Thank you!